# Sitecore User Group Hyderabad - November 2016 Meetup

Tags: support, status-completed, community-event

**About the event:**

We are happy to announce Sitecore Hyderabad User Group meetup new session in November.

With Sitecore 8.2 released end of August 2016, there are new tools and features added to Sitecore arsenal. Come to learn how Sitecore has become more awesome with SXA, Migration tool and new Administration tools.

Sitecore Azure becoming the hot topic, we have a session for it on how to automate boilerplate Sitecore environment installation into Azure using PowerShell

Learn about EXM pipelines and Custom contact token for E-Mail templates in Sitecore EXM Session

**[RSVP to this Event](https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-Hyderabad/events/235323544/)**

**When:**
Date/Time (IST): Friday, November 25, 2016, 5:30 PM - 7:30 PM
Date/Time (UTC): Friday, November 25, 2016, 12:00 PM - 2:00 PM

**Where:** [Techaspect Soultions, Hyderabad, Telangana, India](https://goo.gl/maps/nWVYLxSFxHF2)

---

**Agenda:**
5:30 PM - 5:45 PM - Networking
5:45 PM - 6:15 PM - Sitecore Azure 1-click deploy using PowerShell scripts - *Karthik Jaisimha*
6:15 PM - 6:45 PM - Sitecore EXM - Contact mapping, pipelines and tokens - *Madhukar Reddy*
6:45 PM - 7:15 PM - Introduction to Sitecore 8.2 features - *Venkata Phani Abburi*
7:15 PM - 7:30 PM - Wrap up

---

Contact Person: [Naveen Amanchi](https://twitter.com/navincumar)

Comment: Could you please add the names of the speakers for each of the planned sessions?

Comment: Hi @DmytroShevchenko I've updated post with speaker names..

Comment: will this be broadcasted?

Comment: @Diego Anyone can join remotely to this event by using WebEx. We have updated WebEx details on the RSVP link (given in question). Also note, I think WebEx has max limit of 25 people to join so its advised to come at the event location to attend. ;)